# DFP BannerAd Issue

Tags: ios, google-dfp, adbannerview

I am using DFP Banner Ad with my iOS application But unable to display DFP Banner Ad with example Ad.Unit.ID = "/6499/example/banner" following is the source code

```
self.detail_dfp_bannerview.delegate = self;
self.detail_dfp_bannerview.adUnitID = @"/6499/example/banner";
self.detail_dfp_bannerview.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner;
self.detail_dfp_bannerview.rootViewController = VC;
DFPRequest* req = [DFPRequest request];
req.testDevices = @[@"xxxxxx9b85b85exxxxxxe3b8caxxxxxx"];
[self.detail_dfp_bannerview loadRequest:req];
```

I am using this code in UITableViewCell custom class.
Both callback is working for a single loadRequest

```
(1) - (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {}
(2) - (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)adViewdidFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error{}
```

I am not able to understand what is work with this code
Same code is working if i used

```
self.detail_dfp_bannerview.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxx6099942544/2934xxxxxx";
```

But this is displaying AdMob not DFP,

I am using

```
self.bnrAd.adUnitID = @"/6499/example/banner";
```

then getting following error message

```
Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}
```

Can any one please help me to display DFP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing Size of DFPBannerView issue fixed
Now i am using 320x50 size with DFPBannerView